# RESTEasy error 400 when query param contains curly braces

Tags: rest, resteasy, undertow

Say I have a simple REST endpoint

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String greeting(@QueryParam(value = "name") String name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

If I call it, it works as expected:

```
request: GET http://localhost:8080/hello?name=foo
response: HTTP 200, body "Hello foo"
```

I can also pass encoded curly braces:

```
request: GET http://localhost:8080/hello?name=%7Bfoo%7D
response: HTTP 200, body "Hello {foo}"
```

However, if I put some (not encoded!) curly braces in parameter, I get a error 400 and I cannot see any exception, even with an `ExceptionMapper` configured.

```
request: GET http://localhost:8080/hello?name={foo}
response: HTTP 400, empty body
```

Why? How can I trap this kind of error?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using? What container are you running RESTEasy in?

Comment: I forgot to ask too, what client are you using?

Comment: Running Quarkus 3.5.0 with RESTEasy 6.2.5.Final and microprofile-config 2.1.4

Comment: Tested with Nightingale REST client and Postman

Comment: Using curl worked for me. I don't think this is a RESTEasy issues. I'm seeing, on WildFly, the 400 returned before it even gets to RESTEasy. I assume in my case it's Undertow sending it as it's an invalid URI. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2.